# Email RegEx is stuck in an infinite loop when email address does not have an @ symbol

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, email

I have a RegEx that works for all situations except one, and I cannot figure out why it doesn’t work in this one situation because logic tells me that it should.

The RegEx is for checking if an email address is a valid email address. (**NOTE:** I am familiar with the acceptable email address standards, however I am not looking for a regex that conforms to those standards my employer has it’s own rules on what a valid email address can be)

Can you tell me what is wrong with my RegEx so it works with the valid email address rules I have to work with? (see rules below)

My RegEx is:

`^([\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17})$`

The rules I have to follow and have been using to build this RegEx are:

- Valid characters are all english letters (a-z), all numbers (0-9), the dash (-), underscore (_), period (.), and plus symbol (+).
- The first character of an email address CAN be an underscore (ie: _peter@test.com)
- A dash CAN exist after a period (ie: peter.-@test.com)
- A period CANNOT exist immediately before the @ symbol (ie: peter.@test.com)
- The domain CANNOT start with a dash (ie: peter@-test.com)
- A subdomain CANNOT start with a dash (ie: peter@test.-com)
- A domain or subdomain CANNOT be dashes (ie: peter@--.com) (ie: peter@test.--)

I have been testing the email addresses using this VB.NET code:

```
Public Const EMAIL_VALIDATE_REGEX As String = "^([\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17})$"

Public Function IsEmailAddressValid(ByVal sCheckEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Try
        sCheckEmailAddress = Trim$(sCheckEmailAddress)
        Return Regex.IsMatch(sCheckEmailAddress, EMAIL_VALIDATE_REGEX)
    Catch Exp As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The above RegEx works with all of the rules and returns a proper True or False for all email addresses except this one email address:

> peter.peter.canada.ca

If I use my RegEx on this invalid email address (it’s missing an @ symbol!), my code hangs. I believe I have an infinite loop in my RegEx.

I appreciate any help you can provide in figuring out what is wrong with my RegEx formula that would cause it  to get stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This right here is the problem

```
 (                             # (1 start)
        [\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]
      ( [\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]+ )*      # (2)
 )+                            # (1 end)
```

You can see that both classes are identical and are embedded within
nested quantifiers.

Change it to

```
 (                             # (1 start)
     [\+\-_\.0-9a-zA-Z]+
 )                            # (1 end)
```

And you're good to go.

Note - To maximize efficiency, your regex factors down to this

`^([+\-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+)@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17})$`

```
 ^ 
 (                                 # (1 start)
      [+\-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+ 
 )                                 # (1 end)
 @
 (                                 # (2 start)
      ( [0-9a-zA-Z] [-\w]* \. )+        # (3)
      [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17} 
 )                                 # (2 end)
 $
```

**addendum 1**

`•A period CANNOT exist immediately before the @ symbol`

In this case, just make the period valid if it's surrounded by  a non-period.

`^([-+_0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\.?[-+_0-9a-zA-Z])*)@((?:[0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17})$`

```
 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      [-+_0-9a-zA-Z]+ 
      (?:
           \.?
           [-+_0-9a-zA-Z] 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 @
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?: [0-9a-zA-Z] [-\w]* \. )+
      [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,17} 
 )                             # (2 end)
 $
```

Comment: That works and stops the infinite loop. So i guess the second nested quantifier was what caused the loop. The RegEx doesn't seem to catch the situation where you cannot have a ".@", for example, "peter.@test.com"

Comment: @ThePeter - added addendum 1 for period. Any other changes ?

Comment: If you want a period to be valid at the start (but still not before the @), let me know and I'll do a tweak.

Comment: There should *not* be a period as the first character, so yes please, i'd love to see it tweaked again!

Comment: @ThePete - The way it is in the addendum is a period must be between non-period. And since there is only a single @, no tweaking is needed [^(\[-+_0-9a-zA-Z\]+(?:\.?\[-+_0-9a-zA-Z\])*)@((?:\[0-9a-zA-Z\]\[-\w\]*\.)+\[a-zA-Z0-9\]{2,17})$](https://regex101.com/r/eK8PvN/1)

Comment: It works great. I have tested it against 20+ email variants and it works perfectly.